# Where should I place universal setup code for rails unit tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shoulda

I would like to stub a web service proxy before all my unit tests. I could call some shared code in each unit test, but I was wondering if there is a better way.

I am using Shoulda.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in test/test_helper you can do the following:

```
class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def stub_some_stuff
    …
  end

  setup :stub_some_stuff
end
```

Be careful to ensure you don't just do it once by putting it outside of a setup block, doing so may result in the stub being torn down by the first test, and then all future requests just go straight through!

Answer (score 0):

test/test_helper is a good place for common code - this will be injected into your TestCases